# Twig translate dynamic value/string from database

Tags: twig

***Explanation:***
I pull these values from my local database and try to display them on the front-end. The issue is, that I have 2 languages that I need to cater to.

***Example:***

```
{% if activeLocale == "si" %}
  {{ record.estate_type_SI|raw }}
{% elseif activeLocale == "en" %}
  {{ record.estate_type_EN|raw }}
{% endif %}
```

This works, but when I have multiple items it gets gruesome because I have to write everything down two times. What this does is that depending on the language a value from a different column in the database is pulled.

I am wondering if I can do something similar to this:

```
{{ record.estate_type_{{"SI"|trans}}|raw }}
```

I will gladly buy you a beer if you can help me out with this. 
Cheers!

**EDIT: Variables**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [attribute](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) , you can access a property of an object in a dynamic way. Then you just have to use upper filter to match what you need.

```
{{ attribute(record, 'estate_type_'~ activeLocale|upper)|raw }}
```

Comment: The activeLocale is not a property of the Model/Object, but a property of the page. See the Image that i have added to the question.

Comment: It should not matter. It doesn't wortk -> What is the error? I tested it it works on my website

Comment: Solved. Cheers goto, had a typo. You can PM me your Paypal, i will gladly buy you that promised beer! :)

Comment: ;] i'll virtually drink it